# I have chosen a Pane, but I would like to set the alignment, is it possible?

Tags: javafx, size

I'm doing a project with javafx. As cointainer I choose the Pane, maybe the worst decision! Is it possible to center the text, using the lenght of the sentence which will be loaded according to the size of the panel?

I'm actually showing the code that i wrote. As you can see, the GeneralQuestion lenght will be various, the question has not a min or max character. How can i center it according to the size of the panel?

This is how does it look like: [image]

This is the output, as you can see it isn't centered. I know there's the VBox or other type of panel but i've already chosen this one and before changing everything i would like to know if there's any way to make it look better!

This is the controller:

```
public void nextQuest(ActionEvent e) throws IOException
{
secondaryImg.setVisible(false);
nextQuestionButton.setVisible(false);
getQuestion(cont);
cont++;
}

public void getQuestion(int cont) throws FileNotFoundException, 
IOException
{
FileManager f = new FileManager();
numQuest();
QuestionManager m = new QuestionManager(f.loadQuestion());

                GeneralQuestion.setText(m.getAllQuestion().get(cont).getBody());
answ=m.getAllQuestion().get(cont).getAnswer();

     if(m.getAllQuestion().get(cont).getType().equals("normale")||m.getAllQuestion().get(cont).getType().equals("perditutto"))
answS.setVisible(true);
else if(m.getAllQuestion().get(cont).getType().equals("verofalso")){
RbVero.setVisible(true);
RbFalso.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This is (a part of) the FXML:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #b8ffe0; -fx-border-width: 8px; -fx-border-color: #0e3d73;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="guiz.controller.GameScreenController">
<children>

<Label id="numquest" fx:id="numquest" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="35.0" text="Label">
<font>
<Font size="15.0" />
</font></Label>

<Label fx:id="GeneralQuestion" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="123.0" style="-fx-font-weight: 800;" text="Quest">
<font>
<Font size="18.0" />
</font>
</Label>
</children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Changing a single element name (and adding the appropriate import) can hardly be considered "changing everything". In general you want to avoid `Pane` (and in most cases `AnchorPane` for responsive layouts. It would be possible to bind the `layoutX` property to half the difference of the widths of the parent pane and the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaFX you achieve a desired layout by nesting various layout panes inside each other. Pane is indeed a bad descision because a Pane just does not do any layout at all. In your case a VBox would indeed be a better alternative which you might put into a BorderPane.